# Onclick button create new marker

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

As the title states I'm doing something wrong performing that, I'm assuming I must be doing something wrong with the JS structure making it not working. So far I'm clicking the button the marker does not appear here is the code I'm working with.

```
 function addMyMarker() { //function that will add markers on button click
        var mark = new google.maps.Marker({
            position:mapCenter, 
            map: map,
              draggable:true,
              animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
            title:"This a new marker!",
          icon: "http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/micons/blue.png"
        });   
    }
```

and here is the code entirely with  the above added. Please help. I'm not good with JS.

```
    var map;
var markersArray = [];
var mapCenter = new google.maps.LatLng(10.4167, 123.0000);

   var customIcons = {
  City: {
    icon: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_blue.png',
    shadow: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_shadow.png'
  },
  Municipality: {
    icon: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_red.png',
    shadow: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_shadow.png'
  }
};

    function load() {
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(10.4167, 123.0000),
    zoom: 8,
    mapTypeId: 'roadmap'

    });
    var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;


    downloadUrl("xmlspitter.php", function(data) {
    var xml = data.responseXML;
    var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");
    for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
      var name = markers[i].getAttribute("name");
      var address = markers[i].getAttribute("address");
      var type = markers[i].getAttribute("type");
      var point = new google.maps.LatLng(
          parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lat")),
          parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lng")));
      var html = "<b>" + name + "</b> <br/>" + address;
      var icon = customIcons[type] || {};
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        position: point,
        icon: icon.icon,
        shadow: icon.shadow
      });
      markersArray.push(marker);
      bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html);
    }
    });


    function bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html) {
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    infoWindow.setContent(html);
    infoWindow.open(map, marker);
    });
    }

     function addMyMarker() { //function that will add markers on button click
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position:mapCenter, 
            map: map,
              draggable:true,
              animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
            title:"This a new marker!",
          icon: "http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/micons/blue.png"
        });   
    }

    function downloadUrl(url, callback) {
    var request = window.ActiveXObject ?
    new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP') :
    new XMLHttpRequest;

    request.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (request.readyState == 4) {
    request.onreadystatechange = doNothing;
    callback(request, request.status);
    }
    };

    request.open('GET', url, true);
    request.send(null);
    }


    function doNothing() {}
  }
```

It uses. *************EDIT****************

```
<input type='button' id="drop" onClick="addMyMarker();">
```

Comment: your function addMyMarker() doesn't seem to be used in this code, is it called somewhere else ?

Comment: it has an input type `<input type='button' id="drop" onClick="addMyMarker();">`

Comment: Are you sure the marker is not there?. I put your code into a similar project to yours and the marker appeared at the `mapCenter` I defined.Your `mapCenter`may not be at the center of displayed Map after markers are generated. Zoom out to find. You can set the optimal viewport for the returned results by using LatLngBounds.extend and Map.fitBounds. See [Documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference?hl=en#LatLngBounds)

Answer (score 0):

Try using the global `marker` variable instead of creating a new one...

```
function addMyMarker() { //function that will add markers on button click
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
```

Comment: Tried that earlier still nothing, I moved the code outside the initialization load function